I want bt-agent to stop running after connecting via bluetooth
bt-agent -c NoInputNoOutput
I run this command and when someone is connecting to the device via bluetooth i want this command to stop running but it still running when someone is connecting. how can i force it to stop running when someone is connecting?

Why? If you make it so it stops running when someone is connecting, then that person will be automatically disconnected, and no more connections will be accepted. Is that what you want?
